# Handling Facebook Login

Tags: android, ios, facebook

My question is very simple. Do facebook provide any option to prompt for username and password every time. (I just trying to restrict unauthorized user to login my app using facebook, as it won't ask username/pwd every time, once signed in with facebook then it is always using that session for consecutive login)

Thanks

Comment: Deleting session won't help in this case as credentials are stored with facebook app when you create session it won't prompt again for username password.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use what is known as [Re-authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/reauthentication/), but use it sparingly and only if you really need to verify that it is still the account holder that is using the browser.

Comment: Can we do this from client side, as it requires Java script. Any idea?